# How do I set the default messaging app to use google voice? (4.2.2 Galaxy S4)

Tags: applications, sms, google-voice

I keep seeing advice to set the default messaging app by going to Settings> Manage Applications> All Applications>

And then clicking on the messaging app (I also tried google hangouts since that can send text messages).  But in the "clear defaults" button is greyed out and it says there is no default.  If there is no default, then what is it using to send the message?

I guess a second-best solution is for me to replace the default app with one that can send using google voice.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is the app that can solve your problem...

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.james.SmartUninstaller

I hope it helps! :)

Comment: Explaining how it helps would improve this answer

Comment: Additionally, it would be best if you explain in a brief, specific manner *how to use* this app to solve the specific problem.